# What are the Best Practices that should be used for implementing Cloudwatch logs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

What are the Best Practices that should be used for implementing Cloudwatch logs? I do not see much documentation on the net

Comment: Best practice for what? Archiving the logs, searching, stream, ....?

Comment: Best Practices on how to wisely use CloudWatch

Comment: I'm sorry. In my view the topic is too generic.

Comment: but where do i get the results for what i am looking at